# Hive throws an error when getting a count of distinct rows from a table

Tags: sql, hadoop, distinct, hiveql

I am writing a query to get the count of distinct rows in Hive.

```
select count(*)
from (select distinct 
        uid, 
        site,
        local_date,
        mktg_chnnl_name,
        mktg_sub_chnnl_name from customer_data)
```

But I keep getting this error:

> ParseException line 3:48 cannot recognize input near 'EOF' 'EOF' 'EOF' in subquery source

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

Give your subquery a table alias:

```
select count(*)
from (select distinct uid, site, local_date, mktg_chnnl_name, mktg_sub_chnnl_name 
      from customer_data
     ) cd;
```